# Proving limits using precise definition of limits.

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

$$ \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^3-1}{x-1}=3
$$
How to prove it using precise definition of limits? While solving it, I get stuck at |(x-1)(x+2)|<ε. I don't know how to take out the inequality for x only as this inequality contains quadratic form.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}-3&=x^2+x+1-3\\&=x^2+x-2\\&=x^2-1+x-1\\&=(x-1)(x+1)+x-1.\end{align}Now, take $\varepsilon>0$. If $\lvert x-1\rvert<1$, then $\lvert x+1\rvert<3$ and therefore$$\bigl\lvert(x-1)(x+1)+x-1\bigr\rvert<4\lvert x-1\rvert.$$So, take $\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac\varepsilon4\right\}$ and then$$\lvert x-1\rvert<\delta\implies\bigl\lvert(x-1)(x+1)+x-1\bigr\rvert<4\times\frac\varepsilon4=\varepsilon.$$

Comment: By saying that |x-1|<1 you're apparently saying that X should be between 0 to 2 or x belongs to (0,2). So as a general rule, can I use this assumption everytime I work on such questions? Like x belongs to (3,5) when x tends to 4.

Comment: Yes. But note that I defined $\delta$ as the smallest number between $1$ and $\frac\varepsilon4$. So, this *assures* that $\lvert x-1\rvert<1$.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was saying.

Answer (score 0):

Let $0 <\epsilon<1$. If $|x-1| <\epsilon /4$ then $|\frac {x^{3}-1} {x-1} -3|=|x^{2}+x+1-3|=|(x-1)(x+1)+(x-1)|<|x-1|(|x-1|+2)+|x-1|<(\epsilon/4) (3)+\epsilon/4 <\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

As you've probably noticed, when $x \ne 0$, \frac{x^3-1}{x-1} = x^2 + x + 1$, so you just need to show that |x^2 + x + 1 - 3| = |x^2 + x -2| gets arbitrarily close to 0 (in epsilon delta terms).

Answer (score 0):

The standard trick to deal with this issue is to declare that you will never pick an $x$ outside of $(0,2)$. In other words, no matter what $\varepsilon$ is, your $\delta$ will never be greater than $1$.

With this declaration, we get $|x+2|\leq 4$, and this gives
$$
|(x-1)(x+2)\leq 4|x-1| <4\delta
$$
So as long as $\delta$ is less than or equal to $\frac\varepsilon4$, everything will work fine.

So with the assumption that $\delta\leq 1$, everything works as long as we also have $\delta\leq \frac\varepsilon 4$. Thus one possible choice for $\delta$ will be
$$
\delta = \min\left(1, \frac\varepsilon4\right)
$$
With this choice of $\delta$, and assuming $0<|x-1|<\delta$, we get
$$
\left|\frac{x^3-1}{x-1} - 3\right|= |(x-1)(x+2)|\leq 4|x-1|<4\delta\leq \varepsilon
$$
and we're done.